# strip trailing slash in lib-noir

Tags: java, regex, string, clojure

I'm studying lib-noir library. When I looked into `wrap-strip-trailing-slash` function, I found interesting regex pattern.

```
(defn wrap-strip-trailing-slash
  "If the requested url has a trailing slash, remove it."
  [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (handler (update-in request [:uri] s/replace #"(?<=.)/$" ""))))
```

The author uses `#"(?<=.)/$"` pattern but I could not understand how regex works in the case? 
I tried to find any information from Java Regex Document but couldn't find right information.

`(?<=.)` it looks very interesting. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=.)/$

(?<=.)  # Positive lookbehind
/       # Literal forward slash
$       # End of line anchor
```

The positive lookbehind is a [lookaround assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  that makes sure the following character has something before it that matches the expression inside the assertion.

The expression in the positive lookbehind being the `.` (wildcard in regex to mean any character, by default except newlines), `(?<=.)/$` will match a the forward slash at the end of a string only if that string has another character before the forward slash, in otherwords, if the string is at least 2 characters long.

```
/    # No replace
a/   # Replace the / so that you have the string "a" as result.
a/a  # No replace because / is not at the end of the string.
```